# Parametric Equations on $x= 1 + \sin (\pi t),$ $y= 3 \sin (\pi t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric, parametrization

Consider a particle following the parametric equations
\begin{align*} 
x &= 1 + \sin (\pi t),\\
y &= 3 \sin (\pi t).
\end{align*}a) Give a precise description of the graph of these parametric equations if we allow $t$ to be any real number.

b) Describe the path the particle takes from time $t = 0$ to $t = 2$.

c) Find a parametrization such that the graph of this parametrization from $t = 0$ to $t = 2$ matches our graph above, but the motion of the particle is different.

---

I finished part (a), and I found that the graph covers the line $y=3x-3$ where $x\in[0,2]$. For part (b), I plotted some points out, and I think I know what the answer is. However, I'm having trouble proving the answer. I'm also not sure how to do part (c). I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: One thing to note is that the function is periodic, as when $t = 0, 2 \pi$ both $x$ and $y$ have the same value. So the locus of points traced by the parametric equations is not the same as the actual motion of the particle following these equations. For many continuous functions this is true, but not all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path taken by the particle is on the straight line $y = 3x - 3$ from point $(1,0)$ at $t = 0$ to point $(2.3)$ at $t = \frac 12$ and then from $(2,3)$ in opposite direction to point $(0, -3)$ at $t = \frac 32$. Then finally from $(0, -3)$ back to starting position $(1, 0)$ at $t = 2$.

Now what you are looking for is for the particle to follow a parametric curve with the same graph for $t \in (0, 2)$ but different motion than above. For example, $(t, 3t-3), t \in (0,2)$, where the path is from point $(0,-3)$ at $t = 0$ to $(2,3)$ at $t=2$